# Is the combined salat different from the normal salat?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, combining-prayers

In the sunnah of the prophet, it is known that he would on occasion combine his *salawat*, especially when not doing so would cause hardship (e.g., travelling).  For example, the following practice was narrated by Ibn Abbas:

> The Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him) observed the noon and afternoon prayers together, and the sunset and Isha' prayers together without being in a state of fear or in a state of journey.

When this combined *salat* is performed, in what way (if any) does its form differ from the normal separated *salawat*?  As in, if one were to (hypothetically) combine the dhuhr and asr *salawat*, would they…

- …pray a normal *salat* with eight *rakat*?
- …pray a normal *salat* with four *rakat*, immediately followed by another normal *salat* with four *rakat*?
- …pray a *salat* with eight *rakat*, with a *taslim* and/or *takbir* between the fourth and fifth *rakat*?
- …none of the above?

Comment: Not only you'll have to pray these prayers separately, but you are also recommended to do a separate iqamah (some madhhabs even prefere adhan) for each!. Maliki apparently iqamah for the first, adhan for the second!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is option 2: you pray four first, complete and end it with salaam, and then begin and end another four. This is what is meant by combining prayers. It is permitted to have a short delay between the two since there is a hadith that the Prophet (saws) did that.

Reference: [Fatwa by Shaykh ibn Baz](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/22102/)